# field "_bmStartWord" not found in type CMSBitMap

Tags: jvm, jmap

when run jmap -histo -F , throws exception java.lang.RuntimeException:field "_bmStartWord" not found in type CMSBitMap.

Comment: Which JDK version do you use?

Comment: jdk: 1.8.0_51l64

Comment: I have the same problem:
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)